# Can a 74LVC1G07 handle 12V?

Tags: voltage, open-drain

The 74LVC1G07 is open-drain, but I don't find anything in the datasheet that tells whether or not it can handle 12v on the output ("Y") pin.

Comment: There are various manufacturers, most specify it in the datasheet, you might want to link yours.

Comment: Look in "Absolute Maximum Ratings" (NXP calls it "Limiting values"). I've looked at datasheets from 3 different manufacturers and they all show 6.5V

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to table 5 of the NXP datasheet device can only handle 6.5 V.

For other manufacturers it will make little difference and these also will not support 12 V since this concerns the 74LVC.... series which are intended for a maximum of 5 V typical supply voltage so with tolerances etc. the maximum allowed voltage will be 6.5 V.

If you need 12 V tolerance you will have to use a different IC if that exists or an inverter and an external NMOS which can handle 12 V.

Comment: +1. Perhaps add some specific examples of high-voltage-tolerant open-drain ICs, such as the ULN2003, TPIC6595, TLC6C598, HEF4894, etc.